# How to filter by date & a specific custom post type post-WP 4.4?

Tags: archives, date, custom-post-type-archives, wp-get-archives

WordPress 4.4 introduced the ability to display date archives by appending /?post_type=custom_post_type to the end of the date url. i.e. localhost/2016/02/?post_type=news.

I had assumed I could do: `if( is_post_type_archive('news) && is_date())...`

But from what I can discern:

- is_date() will only detect if the page is displaying a year/month/day archive & is_date() applies to all CPT date archives as well
- is_archive() applies to all archive pages
- is_post_type_archive('CPT') will only apply to the archive page and filters out date archives

I'm trying to output a menu on the news date archive pages to display separately from the blog date archive pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no logical explanation why `if( is_post_type_archive('news) && is_date())` should fail and not work in your situation.

- `is_date()` return true on all date archives
- `is_post_type_archive( 'news' )` will return true on post type archives

When you visit `localhost/2016/02/?post_type=news`, both of those ring true, and they will only ring true on that specific URL

If it it fails, you have something breaking your main query, maybe a bad `pre_get_posts` action or you are using `query_posts` somewhere on the page which will break the main query object. You should do `var_dump( $wp_query )` and inspect the main query object. Specially look at `$query` property

Comment: You are correct. I just re-ran this through a fresh install with the following:

`<?php if(is_date() && is_post_type_archive('news')) { echo 'is_date + is_post_type_archive(news)'; }
    elseif( is_date() && is_post_type_archive('posts')) { echo ' is_date + is_post_type_archive(posts)'; }
    elseif( is_date() && is_archive()) { echo ' is_date + is_archive'; } ?>` 


and it produced:

localhost/2016/ :  `is_date + is_archive`
localhost/2016/?post_type=news : `is_date + is_post_type_archive(news)`
localhost/2016/?post_type=post : `is_date + is_archive`

Comment: Glad it worked. Enjoy ;-)